# Was Tesla familiar with Helmholtz, Maxwell, and Hertz (or vice versa)?

Tags: history

Was Tesla familiar with the theories or experiments of Helmholtz, Maxwell, and Hertz (or *vice versa*)?

Comment: Certainly Maxwell could not have known Tesla, as Maxwell died a few years prior to Tesla's start.

Comment: This seems to be a question about history rather than physics

Comment: did Maxwell do any major experiments?

Comment: And yes, Tesla's work would have been impossible without knowing about Hertz, and Hertz's work depended on Maxwell's work.

Comment: "The Germans, of course, gave us the Hertz-waves… It was an obvious application of the new agent and accomplished with the old classical and unimproved induction coil—scarcely anything more than another kind of heliography. The radius of transmission was very limited, the results attained of little value, and the Hertz oscillations, as a means for conveying intelligence, could have been advantageously replaced by sound-waves, which I advocated in 1891.

Comment: "Moreover, all of these attempts were made three years after the basic principles of the wireless system, which is universally employed to-day, and its potent instrumentalities had been clearly described and developed in America. No trace of those Hertzian appliances and methods remains today."     —Tesla's 1919 autobiography